# The item is removed from the cart but it is not added back to the cart

Tags: javascript, html, css

The item is removed from the cart but it is not added back to the cart when clicking on <kbd>Add to Cart</kbd>.

```js
//function for add to cart for only one item
document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function() {
  myFunc()
};

function myFunc() {
  var x = document.getElementById('itm_img');
  
  document.getElementById('itm1').innerHTML = x.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('rtm').style.display = "block";
}

// function for remove item from cart
document.getElementById('rtm').onclick = function() {
  rtm()
};

function rtm() {
  document.getElementById('itemshow').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.all {
  display: flex;
}

.item_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ffcccc;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5%;
}

.itm_img {
  padding: 2%;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.itm_title {
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="all">
    <div class="item_container">
      <div class="itm_img" id="itm_img">
        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61X1b09mK0L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="img" class="img" id="img">
      </div>
      <div clas="itm_dtl">
        <div class="itm_title" id="itm_title">
          <h3> Milton stainless steel Water Bottle, 1 pc, 950 ml, Silver</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
          <a href="https://www.milton.in/">Visit Milton Store</a>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="price">$19</div>
        <div class="btn">
          <button class="btn1" id="btn1">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item_container">
      <div class="itm_img">
        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61X1b09mK0L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="img" class="img">
      </div>
      <div clas="itm_dtl">
        <div class="itm_title">
          <h3> Milt# # on stainless steel Water Bottle, 1 pc, 950 ml, Silver</h3>
```

When I clicked on <kbd>Add to Cart</kbd> it’s adding the item to the cart, and later when clicking on the remove button, the item is removed but clicking on <kbd>Add to Cart</kbd> again doesn’t add the item back.

Comment: The html code has been removed the code pen link : https://codepen.io/Lalith-/pen/eYKvbRV

Comment: Is this a JS problem, an HTML problem, or a CSS problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: @PentakotaLalithPrasad Please see the edited snippet. [Edit] the snippet and provide a [mre] of your code. Your HTML shouldn’t abruptly stop in the middle; it should be minimal, but _complete_. There is no element with ID `rtm` anywhere in the code you’ve shown here. The `rtm` changes the `display` of `document.getElementById('itemshow')`, but it is never changed back.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Lalith-/pen/eYKvbRV
And I don't know what's the problem is

Comment: Try using your browser’s [debug capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a). Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors. The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** tab. Inspect your elements. What do the applied CSS rules reveal?

Comment: Not showing any error. I was added my codeopen plz check it https://codepen.io/Lalith-/pen/eYKvbRV

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Here in your func `rtm()` you are using `display:none` to remove the item on click of `remove button`, but if want to add item back to cart you should remove remove `display:none` from this `#itemshow`.

`document.getElementById('itemshow').style.display = "block";`
Add this line in the `myFunc()`.

But in this way you are not **technically** adding and removing items from the cart but you are actually hiding and making it visible on clicks.